# automate process to avoid manual update of a column in sql

Tags: sql

i have a table like:

| name | city |
| --- | --- |
| Emma | Athens |
| Edie | Berlin |
| Emma | Athena |
| Edie | Berlins Germany |
| Emma | Athena-Greece |
| Edie | 228 Street, Berlin |

in which i'm trying to change the value of a column city like:
where city like '%Athen%' to be updated as 'Athens'
and city like '%Berlin%' updated to 'Berlin'

i tried to find a solution using replace, ex:

```
select replace(city, '%Athen%', 'Athens') 
from person
where city like '%Athen%'
```

but it doesn't work.

the result of the table should be that:

| name | city |
| --- | --- |
| Emma | Athens |
| Edie | Berlin |
| Emma | Athens |
| Edie | Berlin |
| Emma | Athens |
| Edie | Berlin |

Comment: You're using a select statement and should be using an update statement. The "replace" just returns the result of that replace operation in your select statement results

Comment: If you want to avoid "manual updates" I think that what you really want is to normalize the table to avoid the wrong values to be entered in first place. What about having a table City (CityId INT, CityName VARCHAR(xxx)) and change your Person table to have a FK to it CityId?

Comment: Note that e.g. Berlingen and Athenaz are separate places, and should not be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you possibly after a *searched case* expression?

```
select case
    when city like '%Athen%' then 'Athens'
    when city like '%Berlin%' then 'Berlin'
else city end as City
from person
```

**Edit** - not clear if you are actually trying to update rows but if so you can update all rows at once with as many expressions as required:

```
update person set city=
    case
      when city like '%Athen%' then 'Athens'
      when city like '%Berlin%' then 'Berlin'
      ...
    else city end
```

If you only have the two criteria you can add

`where city like '%Athen%' or city like '%Berlin%'`

Comment: thank you for your answer.my problem is that my table is full of values like that and it's big , so i wonder if there is a way to do it faster without writing every city-case, such as using functions like substring or creating a function with general forms of my data.

Comment: i 'll try to be clear in what i want to do.
i have a big table with values like that and i have to have one name for the same city because, about the above example, it's the same emma who lives in athens and the same edie who lives in berlin, so i have to normalize my table to see only one time each person from each city. 
But first i have to change the values faster than that

Comment: That's information that should have been in your question and really makes it a different question to the one you asked. Don't change your question now though, I would suggest you ask another with as much detail as possible about the actual problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use update statment
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;

```
update person
SET city = 'Athens'
where city like '%Athen%'
```